# How to trigger a click event to skip a next click

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have a next button and previous button, When the active variable is 1 i want to skip the next step 2 and proceed directly to step 3. To attain this i used trigger function. this is my code :

```
    var active = -1;

jQuery('.next').click(function(event){
    if (active < 0) // make sure you only set active value one time
        active = jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step');
        alert(active);
    if(active == '1')
    {   
        active = 0//prevent active being set to 1 again. 
        jQuery(".next").trigger("click");
        // console.log(active);
        active = jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step')+1;
        return false;
    }
```

this is working flawlessly i have a similar prev button and i tried using the same code so that when it reaches step 3 and on next "PREV" button click it should skip a step and goto step 1.

```
jQuery('.prev').click(function(event){
    var active = -1;
    if (active < 0) // make sure you only set active value one time
    {
        active = jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step');
        alert(active);
    if(active == '3')
    {   
        active = 0//prevent active being set to 1 again. 
        jQuery(".prev").trigger("click");
        // console.log(active);
        active = jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step');
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

but here the alert value keep on returning the value 3 in hitting prev button. what is that am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a way to reset the active value before you trigger the click event again, otherwise you end up getting an infinite loop.

Something you could try:

```
var active = -1;

jQuery('.next').click(function(event){
    if (active < 0) // make sure you only set active value one time
        active = jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step');
    if(active == '1')
    {
        active = 0 //prevent active being set to 1 again. 
        jQuery(".next").trigger("click");
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: this methods only works a one time. after that the active holds the value of 0 and nothing else. How can i overcome that.

Comment: Yes and that''s the goal here. Otherwise you function sets active to 1 every time it invoked, and then the if statement always be true, thus cause the function runs again and do the same thing over and over.

Comment: i have a previous button also, so when i hit the previous button and reaches the initial step and clicks the next button this function dosent work cos it still holds the active = 0. how can i overcome that

Comment: Then maybe in your previous button function, you reset the active to be -1, then next time you call the next button function if can runs from the beginning. If you can provide the your full code, I may be able to give you better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

setting the 'active' variable outside the loop is important.

Then, you can just toggle it if you find it set

```
var active = 0;
jQuery('.next').click(function(event){
    active =  jQuery('ul#checkout_timeline').find('li.active').data('step');
    if(active == '1')
    {
        active = 0; // depending on step 3, you may not need this
        // do something to go to step 3 (which is NOT jQuery(".next").trigger("click"); as that causes the infinite loop and error message)
        return false;
    }
    // do whatever step 2 is
});
```

Without clearer code example, it is not possible to help, though this will get rid of the infinite loop and work over and over.